# Deleting exceptions before adding new ones in MS Project VBA

Tags: vba, ms-project

Look for some help on deleting any existing exceptions in the calendar before I add the new ones from my spreadsheet. I'm not sure what else they want me to write.

```
Sub LoadHolidaysFromExcel()

Dim objXL As Object
Dim objWB As Object
Dim objWS As Object

Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

MyFile = objXL.GetOpenFilename

Set objWB = objXL.Workbooks.Open(MyFile)

Set objWS = objWB.Worksheets(1)

'this next line is commented out for running the code, makes it visable
'objXL.Visible = True

objWS.Range("A1").Select
LR = objXL.ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
'Call deleteCalendarExceptions
For x = 1 To LR - 1

MyName = objXL.ActiveCell.Offset(x, 0).Value
MyStart = objXL.ActiveCell.Offset(x, 1).Value
MyFinish = objXL.ActiveCell.Offset(x, 2).Value
MyCalendar = objXL.ActiveCell.Offset(x, 3).Value


ActiveProject.BaseCalendars(MyCalendar).Exceptions.Add Type:=1, Start:=MyStart, Finish:=MyFinish, name:=MyName

Next x


objXL.Workbooks.Close
MsgBox "all done!"
End Sub
```

I've tried the following but it fails

```
For Each x In ActiveProject.BaseCalendars(MyCalendar).Exceptions
    x.Delete
```

Here is the script to deleteCalendarExceptions

```
Sub deleteCalendarExceptions()
Dim e As Exception
Dim CalNam As String
CalNam = ActiveProject.Calendar.name
For Each e In ActiveProject.BaseCalendars(CalNam).Exceptions
    e.Delete
Next e
End Sub
```

Comment: Joe, I see a comment line in your code for, Call DeleteCalendarExceptions. Is that where you tried inserting the code for deleting? Or where exactly did you execute the code line you tried for deletion? Note, you need to delete existing exceptions before you can add new ones. And by the way, when you say it fails, where exactly does it fail and what is the error message?

Comment: Hi John, I'll post the code I were using prior to adding the MyCalendar part

Comment: Joe, using the script to delete calendar exceptions inserted into your macro it runs fine as long as the Project Calendar is set as the "MyCalendar" identified in your Excel Workbook.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Public Sub DeleteExceptions(cal As MSProject.Calendar)

    Dim e As MSProject.Exception
    
    For Each e In cal.Exceptions
        e.Delete
    Next e

End Sub
```